# Is it possible to create Kubernetes statefulset with 0 replicas initially and upgrade later?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, kubernetes-pod

I am creating a statefulset in kubernetes initially with 0 replicas and I will change the replicas value to a number(ex 6 or 7). Does the replicas will be updated or is it possible to create statefulset with 0 replicas?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the above use case and able to create StatefulSet with 0 replica and scale out. Please try and follow the document for more info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/

```
deepak.mourya ~ % kubectl get statefulset        
NAME   READY   AGE
web    0/0     33s

deepak.moury~ % kubectl scale statefulset web --replicas=3
statefulset.apps/web scaled
deepak.mourya ~ % kubectl get statefulset   
NAME   READY   AGE
web    3/3     68s
```